# How to setup and checkout a git repository with vcsrepo in puppet using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, puppet

For test purposes I want to create a bare git repository with puppet and vcsrepo and check out its content on the same machine. I have a `site.pp`that looks as follows:

```
node 'gamma.localdomain' {
   include git
   vcsrepo { "/srv/git/test.git":
      provider => git,
      ensure   => bare,
      require  => Package['git'],
   }
   user { "myuser":
       ensure => present,
   }
   vcsrepo { "/var/tmp/x":
       provider => git,
       ensure => present,
       source  => 'ssh://localhost:22/srv/git/test.git',
       require => User['myuser'],
   }
}
```

The git repository is created, but what must I do to clone it via `ssh`? I have added the public and private key of the user to `.ssh` and added the public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. If I clone the repository via the shell with

```
git clone ssh:\\localhost:22\srv\git\test.git`
```

I must give my password for accessing my private key and the content is checked out. With puppet I get:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[gamma.localdomain]/Vcsrepo[/var/tmp/x]/ensure: Creating repository from present
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/git clone ssh://localhost:22/srv/git/test.git /var/tmp/x' returned 128: Cloning into '/var/tmp/x'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[gamma.localdomain]/Vcsrepo[/var/tmp/x]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/git clone ssh://localhost:22/srv/git/test.git /var/tmp/x' returned 128: Cloning into '/var/tmp/x'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have also tried it with an unencrypted key... The same issue. There must be something which I have not yet understood. Has anybody a hint and can help me?

Answer (score 2):

To make it possible for `puppet` to make SSH connections using your private key, you need to generate one without a passphrase.

As puppet has no way to enter the passphrase, the connection attempt is bound to fail.

Answer (score 0):

To clone the git repository as myuser, you must specify that as a key => value in the Vcsrepo block.  Like below:

```
vcsrepo { "/var/tmp/x":
   user => 'myuser',
   provider => git,
   ensure => present,
   source  => 'ssh://localhost:22/srv/git/test.git',
   require => User['myuser'],
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with user rights, I got same error and when i changed my user to root it worked for me. Like below:

```
file { "/root/.ssh/id_rsa":   #This is required by vcsrepo in require sesion
     ensure => present,
     source => '/vagrant/id_rsa',
}
vcsrepo { '/tmp/test/':
  ensure     => latest,
  provider   => git,
  source     => 'git@gitlab.xyz.git',
  user       => 'root', 
  require    => File["/root/.ssh/id_rsa"],
}
```